# Insert variable in parameter into parametrized build in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Have a Jenkins job with build parameter `BRANCH`. When job run manually user can choose branch from a list to deploy. List provided by git plugin.

But this job also can be invoked by GitLab hook. In this case parameter will have a default value, because didn't receive any input.

Is there a way to have a parameter `BRANCH` with relevant information? With a branch name coming from GitLab hook.

P.S. I think it's possible by set default value to something `${BRANCH_FROM_HOOK ?: default_value}` it will check presence of `BRANCH_FROM_HOOK` variable. Need only find a way how to put into `BRANCH_FROM_HOOK` variable, value of branch coming from hook. I now that gitlab plugin, who receive a hook, set into `gitlab.Branch` value of branch from which hook comes.

UPDATE:
What I have done to achieve this:

- Specify git parameter:

`gitParameter defaultValue: "${env.gitlabBranch ?: "origin/master"}"`
but didn't as `gitlabBranch` is not set on the build start step.

- Setup job parameters as it suggested on gitlab plugin page [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#parameter-configuration):

  - Keep Jenkins Environment Variables
  - Keep Jenkins Build Variables
  - Override Build Parameters
- Added to section "Groovy script":

```
import hudson.model.*
def env = Thread.currentThread()?.executable.parent.builds[0].properties.get('envVars')
def map = [:]

if (env['gitlabBranch'] != null) {
    map['branch'] = env['gitlabBranch'] 
}
return map
```

After this add parameter:

`gitParameter name: branch, defaultValue: "${env.gitlabBranch ?: "origin/master"}"`

to match `map['branch']` as said in doc - not work, also tried:

`gitParameter defaultValue: "${branch ?: "origin/master"}"` - also not worked.

Not worked mean see `origin/master` value, intead of actual branch coming from gitlab hook.

Where I am wrong?

Comment: This is definitely possible. Could you please show a MCVE of what you have tried?

Comment: Just updated my question. Is it something you asked about?

Comment: This is a scripted pipeline?

Comment: No, it's declarative.

Comment: The relevant environment variable `env.BRANCH_NAME` isn't directly available in declarative pipeline. [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/950721) might help; it uses [script](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script) to embed scripted inside declarative.

Comment: Thank you, but I need insert variable BEFORE even build started. On the step where user input build parameters. By your link there a manipulations after build started and me made a checkout from SCM, etc. 

But my parameterized job can be invoked by GitLab hook. And I need that variable coming from GitLab hook will be inserted in one of parameters of job - BRANCH.

Comment: It's easy possible when you run a build manually. Window with input parameters appeared and you can choose a branch to deploy. But when the same job invoked by GitLab hook parameters for a job are default, as if they even was not specified. However later in job checkout doing the right version, because at that time variable are available, but if you open a build parameters there are will be default values what is confusing. I want that the same versions which was using later in job for checkout will be in job parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is use [Generic Webhook plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin), not GitLab. And use it's feature map his variables to parameters of job:

> If your job is parameterized, and you resolve variables that have the
>   same name as those parameters, then the plugin will populate the
>   parameters when triggering job. That means you can, for example, use
>   the parameters in combination with an SCM plugin, like GIT Plugin, to
>   pick a branch.

End.)